# Use API on a WordPress site

Tags: wordpress, api, content-management-system, webservice-client, zabbix

Hello stackoverflow friends

I want to make a portal in wordpress with the Zabbix API. Can I do it in the WordPress platform itself or do I have to write the code elsewhere?

Is this possible?
Does anyone ever tried to do this kind of stuff?
Is there a plugin to call APIs?

I really need an answer to know if it is possible to do this type of things or if I need to look for another type of CMS’s.

Thanks and good work!

Comment: Everything is possible, it all depends on your level of expertise. WordPress supports a lot of things.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible to use that API in WordPress. You can create it as a plugin. Here's more details on how to create a **plugin**, from the official documentation : https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/

To make the API calls, have a look at the **HTTP API** : https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/http-api/

To do database interactions(like saving the data to your db or fetching it), have a look at the **wpdb** class : https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wpdb/

If you want to run cron jobs (scheduled tasks), please have a look at the **WP-Cron**: https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/cron/

There are several built functions, hooks and classes in WordPress that will aid you. Just go through the developer documentation provided by WordPress.